# How to find the last day of a Quarter, Half Year and Year of current Year in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datediff

I would like to get the last day of a Quarter, Half Year and Year of current Year in SQL  Server. Let's say the Current Date is 12-May-2020, the Quarter end date will be 30-June-2020, Half Year date will be 30-June-2020 and Year end date will be 31-December-2020.

I am able to get the last date of Quarter and Year using DATEADD and DATEDIFF built-in functions but unable to get the last date of Half Year.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tag `datediff`, this is a solution using `dateadd` / `datediff`

```
; with dates as
(
    select  [date] = convert(date, '2020-01-01')
    union all
    select  [date] = dateadd(month, 1, [date])
    from    dates
    where   [date]  < '2020-12-01'
)
select  [date],
        dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter, 0, [date]) + 1, -1) as [Last Day of Quarter],
        dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter, 0, [date]) / 2 * 2 + 2, -1) as [Last Day of Half Year],
        dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, [date]) + 1, -1) as [Last Day of Year]
from    dates
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb68e5be9d684c6dd4363db8c5ef73d7)